# Check if all rows in one sub query has all rows in another sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014

A policy have a set of `insuranceTypes` in `PolicyCoverage`.
A policy have a set of `insuranceTypes` for a specific organization in `PolicyPermissionInsuranceType`. 
I'm trying to get the policies that have **all** the insurance types form `PolicyCoverage` in `PolicyPermissionInsuranceType` for a specific organization, user and permission.

In C# I evaluate the rule (for a single policy when found for an organization) as:

```
 public class ReadPolicyLimitedPermission
 {
        private IEnumerable<Guid> InsuranceTypeIds { get; }

        public bool Validate(Policy entity)
        {
            return !entity.InsuranceTypes.Except(InsuranceTypeIds).Any();
        }
 }
```

I'm trying to write a query equal to that rule for all policies in the database. The query I have looks as follow, but is really slow when supplied with a `userId` that does not have a record in the table.
So the question is, is there a better way to perform this type of check?

Query:

```
declare @UserId uniqueidentifier = newId() --Does not exist
declare @Permission nvarchar(150) = 'ReadPolicyLimitedPermission'

select p.Id
from test.Policy p
where
not exists
(
    select 
        pc.insuranceTypeId
    from
        test.PolicyCoverage pc
    where
        pc.PolicyId = p.Id

    except

    select
        ppit.InsuranceType 
    from
        test.PolicyPermissionInsuranceType ppit
    where
        ppit.UserId = @UserId and
        ppit.Permission = @Permission and
        ppit.OrganizationId = p.OrganizationId
)
```

Table sizes:

```
Policy 201762 rows
PolicyCoverage 393004 rows
PolicyPermissionInsuranceType 36984 rows
```

Execution plan:
[image]

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [test].[Policy](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OrganizationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [test].[PolicyCoverage](
    [PolicyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [InsuranceTypeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [test].[PolicyPermissionInsuranceType](
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OrganizationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Permission] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [InsuranceType] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PolicyPermissionInsuranceType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [OrganizationId] ASC,
    [Permission] ASC,
    [InsuranceType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Or is it possible to store the data in a different way for table `PolicyPermissionInsuranceType`

Example:

```
Policy 1
  -Org 1 
    -Type 1
    -Type 2
Policy 2
  -Org 1
    -Type 1
    -Type 3


PolicyPermission 1
-Org1
-Type1
-Type2
-Type5
```

The they query should return Policy1 since it has all the types in the policyPermission table (Type1, Type2) but not Policy2 since it has Type3 which the PolicyPermission1 does not have.

Comment: it might be useful to create a simplified example with sample data, i'm struggling to understand the query with no sample data.

Comment: I'm gonna try to put an example together @Tanner

Answer (score 1):

what if you try this:

```
select a.id from (
    select p.id,ppt.userid From test.Policy p
    join test.PolicyCoverage pc on pc.policyid = p.id
    left join test.PolicyPermissionInsuranceType ppt on ppt.InsuranceType = pc.insurancetypeid
      and ppt.OrganizationId = p.OrganizationId
      and ppt.UserId = @UserId 
      and ppt.Permission = @Permission 
)a
group by a.id
having  COUNT(a.id) = COUNT(a.userid)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer as I wanted to add some code you could test, so didn't seem suited to a comment. Will happily delete unless you find it useful.

You could look to create the second table in your subquery in advance as a temp table and then reference that in the subquery, which might speed things up:

```
declare @UserId uniqueidentifier = newId() --Does not exist
declare @Permission nvarchar(150) = 'ReadPolicyLimitedPermission'

-- temp table here
select ppit.InsuranceType, ppit.OrganizationId 
into #temp
from test.PolicyPermissionInsuranceType ppit
where ppit.UserId = @UserId and
      ppit.Permission = @Permission

-- original modified query with temp table
select p.Id
from test.Policy p
where
not exists
(
    select pc.insuranceTypeId
    from test.PolicyCoverage pc
    where pc.PolicyId = p.Id

    except

    select ppit.InsuranceType 
    from #temp ppit        
    where ppit.OrganizationId = p.OrganizationId
)
```